# Read content of an image in Excel file - with Perl

Tags: excel, image, perl

I have XLSX/XLSM file that contains embedded images. I use Spreadsheet::XLSX to extract textual values - so far, so good. However, it looks like there is no easy way how to get image from Excel sheet in Perl. (Yes, I have searched a bit.) My code will run on Linux server - I´d like to avoid installing Win32::OLE, if possible.

My first idea was to convert XLSX->ODS, open the woorkbook as zip and get image files from there. Problem: I don´t know how to map images and the *content.xml* file yet. (Possible solution: Name images according to cell coordinates & sheet? - Not possible for me now.)

I will appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be of much help but take a look at a post right here on stackoverflow.com and credited to user Sire Hugolin:

[Perl Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX how to get images from Excel file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34792918/perl-spreadsheetparsexlsx-how-to-get-images-from-excel-file)

Granted, it is not Perl but sounds like a similar situation you are facing.